# backbuffer in Linux Xlib (no OpenGL)

Tags: linux, xlib

I would like to know is it possible to get access to pixel data of
Pixmap or XImage. I would like to get a pointer to video memory of 
a Pixmap or XImage. And then after I write to it I want to bit blit it to 
a window , like it is a backbuffer. 
(In Windows I use CreateDIBSection for this purpose.)
I am hoping not to use OpenGL, just Xlib functions.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is that what are you looking for:

http://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/xextproto/shm.html

?

Comment: Currently I am not interested in performance. Also I am new to Linux programming. Do I really need shared memory, I would prefer something like this:  PixmapPixelPtr  https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/BlitzMax/Modules/Graphics/Pixmaps . Just want a pointer to data and ability to bit blit, can it be done in Xlib?

Comment: X server (program that work with hardware [video card]) work with x clients (your program) via sockets, so you can create pixmaps inside your program and copy them again inside your program, but when you want to draw your pixmap on screen, you have to send them via socket or just `bit blit` them to ximage in shared memory.